# BibLatex - replace comma between publisher and year field

Tags: biblatex

I have a question concerning `biblatex`, specifically the publisher field.
I want to replace the comma between the publisher and the year with a semicolon.

This:

> `publisher, year`

should become this:

> `publisher; year`

After researching the documentation of `biblatex`, I found some possible delimiter options, but they don't work.
Which option is the right one?
I included the ones I already tried in the minimal example.

This is the obligatory minimal example:

`minimal.tex:`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, chapteratlists=0pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}%

\usepackage[
style=alphabetic-verb,%
backend=bibtex8,%
bibstyle=alphabetic,
block=ragged,%
isbn=true,%
firstinits=true,%
%dashed=false,%
maxbibnames=99,%
sorting=nty,%
language=german,%
backrefstyle=three+,%
]{biblatex}

%Already tried:
%\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
%\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{publisher}{#1\addsemicolon}%
%\DeclareFieldFormat{location}{#1\addsemicolon}%
%\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\nopunct#1\addsemicolon}

\addbibresource{minimal.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bib file `minimal.bib`:

```
@BOOK{BossOstendorf.2010,
  title = {title},
  year = {1990},
  author = {author},
  volume = {123},
  publisher = {publisher}
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot to moewe. It works now. I will research the commands, so i can do it myself next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the `bibmacro` `publisher+location+date`; put this into your preamble

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper, 11pt, twoside, chapteratlists=0pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}%

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic-verb,
  backend=bibtex8,
  bibstyle=alphabetic,
  block=ragged,
  isbn=true,
  firstinits=true,
  maxbibnames=99,
  sorting=nty,
  backrefstyle=three+]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\nocite{wilde}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: @schwarz1603 This solution will print "place, year" if there is no publisher provided. Do you want "place; year" instead?

Comment: yes, that would be great. I need the semicolon as a separator between every unit for all types of literature. Thanks.

Comment: @schwarz1603 I have updated the answer to add a semicolon between "place; year" if need be.